# Can't Insert dataframe to SQLite table when column names different dbWriteTable

Tags: r, dbi, rsqlite

I am using an SQLite database in R. To insert a data frame into an SQLite table using **dbWriteTable** from DBI, it seems that I need to have the same column names in the data frame as those in the table.
I was using **sqldf** and this was not a condition, it just insert based on the order of columns.
Is there a way to change the behaviour of **dbWriteTable** to accept my data frame.
Here is an example code with both **dbWriteTable** and **sqldf**

```
library(RSQLite)
library(sqldf)

path = "data_base.sqlite"

conn = DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(),path)
dbExecute(conn, "CREATE TABLE sales(Items INT, Sales REAL)")

df1 = data.frame(Items = c(12,14,5), Sales = c(111.6,130.2,46.5))
dbWriteTable(conn,name = "sales",value = df1, append=TRUE, row.names=FALSE)

df2 = data.frame(Nombre = c(2,6,9), Ventes = c(18.6,55.8,83.7))
dbWriteTable(conn,name = "sales",value = df2, append=TRUE, row.names=FALSE)

sqldf("insert into sales select * from `df2`",dbname = path)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Up front**, this is a really bad idea: if the columns are in the wrong order or if there is an incorrect number of columns, then this will produce unpredictable (or just bad) results.

Having said that, rename the frame's column names before uploading.

```r
df2 = data.frame(Nombre = c(2,6,9), Ventes = c(18.6,55.8,83.7))
names(df2)
# [1] "Nombre" "Ventes"
names(df2) <- dbListFields(conn, "sales")
names(df2)
# [1] "Items" "Sales"
dbWriteTable(conn,name = "sales",value = df2, append = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
DBI::dbGetQuery(conn, "select * from sales")
#   Items Sales
# 1    12 111.6
# 2    14 130.2
# 3     5  46.5
# 4     2  18.6
# 5     6  55.8
# 6     9  83.7
```

If you don't want to change the names (for some reason) of `df2`, then you can do it "inline":

```r
dbWriteTable(
  conn, name = "sales",
  value = setNames(df2, dbListFields(conn, "sales")),
  append = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
```

Other than that, then ... **No**, you should not change `dbWriteTable` to ignore column names and just assume things are aligned.

Comment: Clever solution. I am not sure if and when R does create a copy of the data.frame though (could be added to the answer to make it a "premium answer" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The column names must correspond.  Ignore the warning or use `sqldf2` defined [here](https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf/issues/40) to muffle it.

```
sqldf("insert into sales select Nombre as Items, Ventes as Sales from df2",
   dbname = path)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was asking if we can do this with dbWriteTable.